# Can php or javascript on client link to remote server database?

Tags: php, javascript, oracle, client-server

I have access to a remote Oracle database when using Toad or SQL Developer.
The connection is specified by a TNS record and user+password of course.

Now I wish to have a local webpage that shows (regularly refreshed) data from the database. At first I was thinking of using php but I guess that can only be used on the server itself and I am unable to create files on the server. Of course a server page would be more suitable when there's multiple users but here there's only one.

In fact I just want to do the same as is done by running queries from the tools mentioned, but now called from a custom webpage. I feel this should be possible because the tool has to establish the connection from client to server db also; but I don't know how to set up my local client webpage(s).

Is this possible by applying php or javascript if that's more suitable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you have to understand that the functionality of connecting to oracle database is packaged as part of frameworks, there are no such frameworks in javascript which can help you.

you are right with php, however it needs a webserver to run and they are free :)

the reason why php can connect to oracle database is, it has the framework to do those operations.

for now the answer is `no`.

or you can see if you can write an `Activex` which can connect to Oracle database and refresh, microsoft provides framework / api to connect to databases

Comment: Are you suggesting that I should use a local php and run it from EasyPHP or the like? Will this be able to connect to the remote db as if it were a server php?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do that kind of thing is AJAX: a javascript code calls a PHP page on the web server, this page connects to the DB and returns data to the javascript that updates the page.

Comment: No it can't. Javascript is a client side language, it's not supposed to deal with any database.